# Page scraping using ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I need to create a new layout dynamically using ColdFusion by scraping the top and bottom of the page and saving as 2 different variables.

The top stops at the top until this.

```
googleoff: all (This is in an HTML Comment)
```

The bottom starts at this

```
googleon: all (This is in an HTML comment)
```

until the end.

I am thinking that I can use regular expressions to do this.

Comment: No. Just use string functions, that would be easier.

Comment: Can you please expand a little please?

Comment: Regex would be overhead. Just use the string manipulation tools that were given to you by the language, to search for exact strings and to slice substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that these comments only occur in the positions you have stated, you can easily do this with a regex string split:

```
<cfset Sections = String.split( '<!-- google(?:on|off): all -->' ) />

<cfset TopOfPage    = Sections[1] />
<cfset BottomOfPage = Sections[3] />
```

An updated regex would be needed if they comments are not fixed - for example, you can replace the spaces with `\s*` if the whitespace is unpredictable.

For comparison, here's a non regex version:

```
<cfset EndOfTopPos      = find( '<!-- googleoff: all -->' , String ) - 1 />
<cfset StartOfBottomPos = find( '<!-- googleon: all -->' , String , EndOfTopPos ) + 22 />

<cfset TopOfPage    = left( String , EndOfTopPos ) />
<cfset BottomOfPage = right( String , len(String)-StartOfBottomPos ) />
```

Since this works with fixed strings, it is faster - but you would need to be repeating this several thousand times before this difference might be significant.